# Global variable isn't using the same instantiation shared across all views

Tags: swift, swiftui

Below is my class that holds a string to determine whichCountry it is. I'm trying to make sure that they all share the same views

```
import Foundation

class GlobalData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var whichCountry: String = "italy"
}
```

The is my IndepthView view where I start everything. I create the EnvironmentObject to the globalData class. From there I pass it to another view and a method that I use to update information in the IndepthView

```
import SwiftUI

struct InDepthView: View {
    @State var showList = false
    @EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData
    @ObservedObject var data = getDepthData(globalData: GlobalData())

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    }
  }
}
```

I then pass the globalData variable to my other view to update the string to "usa". I also check to make sure that it was being updating correctly.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListOfCountriesView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                Text("List of Countries")
                    .padding(.top, 25)

                    Button(action: {
                        self.globalData.whichCountry = "usa"
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("usa)")
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                            Divider()
                        }

                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListOfCountriesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListOfCountriesView().environmentObject(GlobalData())
    }
}
```

But when I get to my class getDepthData() it isn't show the modified text and just displaying "italy" when it should be displayinh "usa". Im not quite sure how do I pass the globalData variable across everything to make sure it has the same inst

```
class getDepthData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var data : Specific!
    @Published var countries : HistoricalSpecific!
    var globalDatam: GlobalData

    init(globalData: GlobalData) {
        globalDatam = globalData
        print(globalDatam.whichCountry + " init()")
        updateData()
    }

    func updateData() {

        let url = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/" // specific country

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url+"\(self.globalDatam.whichCountry)")!) { (data, _, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            let json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Specific.self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = json
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two instances of the GlobalData object in your InDepthView. However you passed the EnvironmentObject instance to the view, you should use that same instance to create the "data" variable in the initializer, rather than doing it inline like you do here:

```
@EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData
@ObservedObject var data = getDepthData(globalData: GlobalData())
```

So, if you're in the parent view of InDepthView, you can initialize it like this:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData

    var body: some View {
       ...
        IntDepthView(data: getDepthData(globalData: self.globalData))
       ...
    }
}
```

Depending on how frequently that parent view gets redrawn, there are other ways. Anyway, looks to me like the getDepthData object has it's own instance of GlobalData, and not the updated EnvironmentObject instance.